# Datasheet of an unknown IC

Tags: schematics, datasheet

When reading the [Platinum Resistance Thermometer Manual](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9ct0was7pc3l57/MN-PRT016.pdf), I was faced with this unknown IC (see pp. 38 from the manual):

[image: Schematic]

I searched the web with the following keywords: **`SON044`** and **`1020B-44`**, but didn't get any meaningful results back.

I think it should be a kind of FPGA.

**What is it? Would anyone please introduce it to me?**

Comment: I don't think it's an FPGA, possibly a CPLD or PLD. They've given it a name that includes a contraction of their company name, so I would assume it contains custom programming for this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line ("1020B-44") suggests that this is an Actel ACT 1 nonvolatile FPGA (A1020B) in a PLCC-44 package. A number of the pin assignments match up perfectly, and the manual that you've got mentions the FPGA in a few places.

Here's the datasheet: http://www.actel.com/documents/ACT1_DS.pdf